# Github pages downloading file fails with "No file" when file is in a directory within a directory, but succeeds when inside only one directory

Tags: html, file, download, github-pages

I can't get the download links to work on my github pages @ https://madisonsmash.github.io/Slippi/ (when you click on the "Browse all replays" link under one of the tournaments, the links to the right of the page should download the specified file - file structure can be found here: https://github.com/madisonsmash/Slippi).

Right now the replays sit inside of ./replays/${tournament name}/, and when I set the href equal to "replays/${tournament name}/${replay name}", the download fails. I've tried typing out the path by hand and removing spaces from the tournament name and the download still fails. However, if I put them inside of "replays" without the second directory, they download without fail (such as in this version of the site: https://andrew-bbq.github.io/SlippiHost/). However, I would like to have the replays organized inside of replays/ within directories for my sanity's sake. Is there anyone who knows why this might be happening?